# How do I reliably scale matplotlib pcolormesh plots for large data sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data using a `pcolormesh` from the `matplotlib.pyplot` but I'm having some difficulty when saving the output (specifically, in scaling the image appropriately).

I'm using Python v3.4 with matplotlib v1.51 if that makes a difference.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def GetData(data_entries, num_of_channels):
    data_dict = {'timestamp' : np.linspace(1, data_entries*21, data_entries, endpoint=True)}

    for chan in range(0, num_of_channels, 1):
        data_dict['random%03d'%chan] = np.random.rand(data_entries, 1).flatten()
        num_at_each_end_to_highlight = 10
        data_dict['random%03d'%chan][0:num_at_each_end_to_highlight] = 1.5
        data_dict['random%03d'%chan][-num_at_each_end_to_highlight:] = 1.5

    for chan in range(0, num_of_channels, 1):
        data_dict['periodic%03d' % chan] = np.zeros(data_entries)#.flatten()
        data_dict['periodic%03d' % chan][::65] = 5000

    return pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

def GetSubPlotIndex(totalRows, totalCols, row):
    return totalRows*100+totalCols*10+row

def PlotData(df, num_of_channels, field_names):
    # Calculate the range of data to plot
    data_entries = len(df.index)

    # Create the x/y mesh that the data will be plotted on
    x = df['timestamp']
    y = np.linspace(0, num_of_channels - 1, num_of_channels)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    # Iterate through all of the field types and produce one plot for each but share the X axis
    for idx, field_name in enumerate(field_names):

        # Create this sub-plot
        subPlotIndex = GetSubPlotIndex(len(field_names), 1, idx + 1)
        ax = plt.subplot(subPlotIndex)
        if idx is 0:
            ax.set_title('Raw Data Time Series')
        # Set the axis scale to exactly meet the limits of the data set.
        ax.set_autoscale_on(False)
        plt.axis([x[0], x[data_entries-1], 0, num_of_channels - 1])
        # Set up the colour palette used to render the data.
        # Make bad results (those that are masked) invisible so the background shows instead.
        palette = plt.cm.get_cmap('autumn')
        palette.set_bad(alpha=0.0)
        ax.set_axis_bgcolor('black') # Set the background to zero

        # Grab the data and transpose it so we can stick it in the time series running along the X axis.
        firstFftCol = df.columns.get_loc(field_name + "%03d"%(0))
        lastFftCol = df.columns.get_loc(field_name + "%03d"%(num_of_channels - 1))
        data = df.ix[:,firstFftCol:lastFftCol]
        data = data.T # Transpose so that time runs along the X axis and bin index is on the Y

        # Mask off data with zero's so that it doesn't obscure the data we're actually interested in.
        data = np.ma.masked_where(data == 0.0, data)

        # Actually create the data mesh so we can plot it
        z_min, z_max = data.min().min(), data.max().max()
        p = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y, data, cmap=palette, vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)

        # Render it
        plt.plot()

        # Label the plot and add a key
        plt.ylabel(field_name)
        plt.colorbar(p)

    # Label the plot
    plt.xlabel('Time (ms)')

    # Record the result
    plt.savefig('test.png', edgecolor='none', transparent=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_entries = 30000 # Large values here cause issues
    num_of_channels = 255

    fields_to_plot = ('random', 'periodic')

    data = GetData(data_entries, num_of_channels)

    width_in_pixels = len(data.index)+200
    additional_vertical_space_per_plot = 50
    num_of_plots = len(fields_to_plot)
    height_in_pixels = (num_of_channels+additional_vertical_space_per_plot)*num_of_plots
    dpi = 80 # The default according to the documentation.
    fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(width_in_pixels/dpi, height_in_pixels/dpi), dpi=dpi)

    PlotData(data, num_of_channels, fields_to_plot)
```

With 1000 entries, the result looks fine:

[image]

If I increase the number of samples to the sort of size I actually want to plot (30000), the image is the correct size (30200 pixels wide) but I see a lot of dead space. This is a zoomed-out summary of the issues I see:

[image]

Is there a way to more accurately fill the image with the data?

Comment: Have you tried adding something like `, pad=0.005` to the `plt.colorbar(p)` line? I get a `ValueError: width and height must each be below 32768` but this might be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387231/limiting-factors-for-saving-a-huge-figure-with-lots-of-subplots-as-a-pdf-documen) question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the prompt from @Dusch, this seems to solve things rather neatly:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def GetData(data_entries, num_of_channels):
    data_dict = {'timestamp' : np.linspace(1, data_entries*21, data_entries, endpoint=True)}

    for chan in range(0, num_of_channels, 1):
        data_dict['random%03d'%chan] = np.random.rand(data_entries, 1).flatten()
        num_at_each_end_to_highlight = 10
        data_dict['random%03d'%chan][0:num_at_each_end_to_highlight] = 1.5
        data_dict['random%03d'%chan][-num_at_each_end_to_highlight:] = 1.5

    for chan in range(0, num_of_channels, 1):
        data_dict['periodic%03d' % chan] = np.zeros(data_entries)#.flatten()
        data_dict['periodic%03d' % chan][::65] = 5000

    return pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

def GetSubPlotIndex(totalRows, totalCols, row):
    return totalRows*100+totalCols*10+row

def PlotData(df, num_of_channels, field_names):
    # Calculate the range of data to plot
    data_entries = len(df.index)

    # Create the x/y mesh that the data will be plotted on
    x = df['timestamp']
    y = np.linspace(0, num_of_channels - 1, num_of_channels)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    # Iterate through all of the field types and produce one plot for each but share the X axis
    for idx, field_name in enumerate(field_names):

        # Create this sub-plot
        subPlotIndex = GetSubPlotIndex(len(field_names), 1, idx + 1)
        ax = plt.subplot(subPlotIndex)
        if idx is 0:
            ax.set_title('Raw Data Time Series')
        # Set the axis scale to exactly meet the limits of the data set.
        ax.set_autoscale_on(False)
        plt.axis([x[0], x[data_entries-1], 0, num_of_channels - 1])
        # Set up the colour palette used to render the data.
        # Make bad results (those that are masked) invisible so the background shows instead.
        palette = plt.cm.get_cmap('autumn')
        palette.set_bad(alpha=0.0)
        ax.set_axis_bgcolor('black') # Set the background to zero

        # Grab the data and transpose it so we can stick it in the time series running along the X axis.
        firstFftCol = df.columns.get_loc(field_name + "%03d"%(0))
        lastFftCol = df.columns.get_loc(field_name + "%03d"%(num_of_channels - 1))
        data = df.ix[:,firstFftCol:lastFftCol]
        data = data.T # Transpose so that time runs along the X axis and bin index is on the Y

        # Mask off data with zero's so that it doesn't obscure the data we're actually interested in.
        data = np.ma.masked_where(data == 0.0, data)

        # Actually create the data mesh so we can plot it
        z_min, z_max = data.min().min(), data.max().max()
        p = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y, data, cmap=palette, vmin=z_min, vmax=z_max)

        # Render it
        plt.plot()

        # Label this sub-plot
        plt.ylabel(field_name)

        # Sort out the color bar
        fig = plt.gcf()
        image_width = fig.get_size_inches()[0] * fig.dpi  # size in pixels
        colorbar_padding_width_in_pixels = 20
        colorbar_padding = colorbar_padding_width_in_pixels/image_width
        plt.colorbar(p, pad=colorbar_padding)

    # Label the plot
    plt.xlabel('Time (ms)')

    # Record the result
    plt.savefig('test.png', edgecolor='none', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight')

    plt.tight_layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_entries = 30000 # Large values here cause issues
    num_of_channels = 255

    fields_to_plot = ('random', 'periodic')

    data = GetData(data_entries, num_of_channels)

    width_in_pixels = len(data.index)+200
    additional_vertical_space_per_plot = 50
    num_of_plots = len(fields_to_plot)
    height_in_pixels = (num_of_channels+additional_vertical_space_per_plot)*num_of_plots
    dpi = 80 # The default according to the documentation.
    fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(width_in_pixels/dpi, height_in_pixels/dpi), dpi=dpi)

    PlotData(data, num_of_channels, fields_to_plot)
```

The secret sauce in the end was:

1. Add `plt.tight_layout()` immediately before the `plt.savefig` call.
2. Add `bbox_inches='tight'` to the `plt.savefig` call.
3. Add `, pad=colorbar_padding` after calculating `colorbar_padding` by checking what proportion of the overall image width a 20 pixel padding equates to.